# High capacity 3.7 V

Tags: 18650

I want to combine 10 18650 3000 mAh cells together in parallel keeping my 3.7 V just increasing my original 15 Ah capacity solar light/charger. The original 15 Ah battery had a tiny 1s BMS that for some reason won't charge the 30 Ah pack at all, allows a charged pack to power the light, once the pack drains that's it. Bypassing that original and hooking the pack directly to the light/charger wiring the light gets full load current, really bright light that slowly dims and once drops to a 2.5 V area the main board shuts down the power. What do I need to add to manage outgoing current so I'm not dumping too much current in the beginning. Bypassing the 1st tiny board I get recharged, but in use I get super bright lights slowly draining to auto shutoff in the same timeframe i was getting steady light. Solar charge puts out 16 W at 6 V.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic.

Comment: Does a BMS charge a battery?